# Attaching Event Handlers Optimization JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<div id='test'>
 <a href='#'>Link 1</a>
 <a href='#'>Link 2</a>
 <a href='#'>Link 3</a>
 <a href='#'>Link 4</a>
 <a href='#'>Link 5</a>
 <a href='#'>Link 6</a>
 <a href='#'>Link 7</a>
 <a href='#'>Link 8</a>
 ...
 <a href='#'>Link n</a>
</div>
```

How to handle `onclick` event on all anchor tags [30 < n < 50].
Is it good to attach `onclick`  event on individual anchor tags? I can't use any JavaScript libraries.
It would be helpful to know jQuery handle `$('.test a').click()` it. How are they able to pass proper `this` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could delegate click handling to the `div`, then check the target inside the handler and act according to which anchor was clicked.

```
var div = document.getElementById('test');
div.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    console.log(event.target.innerHTML)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nrVS9/

**Warning**: IE versions before 9 do not support `addEventListener`. If you need to support those browsers, check if `addEventListener` is available, and use `attachEvent` if it's not.

Comment: @bfarvaretto Thanks for warning, Also consider adding event.srcElement and event = event || window.event

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using something like the following:

```
function callback(e) {
    var e = window.e || e;

    if (e.target.tagName !== 'A')
        return;

    // Do something
}

if (document.addEventListener)
    document.addEventListener('click', callback, false);
else
    document.attachEvent('onclick', callback);
```

In addition ofc, I'd recommend attaching a pseduo-attribute to each anchor that has the number (1-50) so you could use that to detect which of the anchors the user clicked.

you can set `this` by calling function with `function.call(element, arg1, arg2, ...)` or `function.apply(element, [arg, arg2, arg3, ...])`

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('test').onclick = function(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    if(event.target.nodeName == "a"){
        console.log("link clicked");
    }
});
```